# Safari specific CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, safari

I'm trying to help a friend with a blog on wordpress.com http://mpiedgeworldclass.wordpress.com/.

They have the css editing option paid for/turned on so we can edit css but can't touch the theme itself.

There is a vertical image repeating between the sidebar and content area.  It runs too high in Safari but works fine in Chrome.

[image: a safari css issue]

If I could access the theme / html I think this would be easy to fix, but trying to do it only from the css.... I'm not sure if this one is even possible.

Any CSS wizards got any ideas?

(I sincerely wish I had more css skills, but it doesn't seem to come easily nor after 6 years very quickly either.)  :(

Comment: Gonna need to see some code.

Comment: [Conditional CSS](http://www.conditional-css.com/usage) will give you the tools to use CSS to target Safari specifically. As far as this particular issue goes you'll definitely need to share code.

Comment: try using conditional css.

Comment: I generally work in self hosted wordpress from .org not on the wordpress.com site.  

Is it possible to use Conditional CSS in the wordpress.com environment?

As to code here's the css file is too long (too many characters to post here)

Comment: I think with a question like this, seeing the original code wouldn't help much. You can see everything you need in the web inspector, and that's what I would do even if I had access to all the original files. I also think it's best to avoid conditional CSS when possible, especially when it's targeting specific browsers (rather than features).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing is a bit of a mess, but the best solution I can find (which has no effect on Chrome), is to set `height: 187px;` on #header.

It's an interesting issue, where Safari treats margins differently depending on whether you defined the height or not, even though the calculated height for auto comes out to the same value. I had a similar issue the other day.

Comment: :) Thanks for the suggestion.  This is definitely a bit of a mess and not the way I'd normally approach things if I had the choice.  Sometimes being forced to do things like this does teach you something.

Anyway, I did set the height and it does seem to fix Safari.  It slightly effects Chrome by pushing the vertical blue image (bar) down creating 1 pixel of gap in Chrome, no gap in Safari.  That's probably going to have to be the trade off we have to make I suspect.

Comment: That's interesting, it doesn't make a 1px gap for me. Another thing you can do is set position: relative; on #header, to make it go on top. There's still the issue of the content being offset, but then you could set the height to 186px; to get rid of the gap. Hacky, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Safari and Chrome are both based on WebKit and, as such, have no inherent differences when it comes to css rendering.  However if your chrome browser is using a different version of webkit than your safari's you could potentially see some issues.  This problem looks to be either a position or display issue...which havent really changed as far as I know.

What I would do is check to see if the css is doing anything new or weird in order to place that element which is the likely cause of the problem.  Code would really help, but I can suggest checking the respective versions of safari and chrome and perhaps update them both to their latest builds.  At the very least you'll know it is a backwards compatibility issue if updating them fixes the problem.